# Visual Studio Navision 2018 error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to create table and page Navision through visual studio code. but I am finding an error in this process. Can anyone help me?

**Error: Could not open the specified startup page. Please check that the server configuration key PublicWebBaseUrl has been properly set.**

I'm using Navision 2018.

Comment: Please editing your question and add your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. You need to set the PublicWebBaseUrl property. You can do this in two places:

1. Edit the config file of the nav service you are trying to connect to
2. In the server administrator app the same property is under Client
   Services tab called "Web Client Base Url".

[Here it is in the Server Administration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK4t8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following 3 Steps:

1. Set the PublicWebBaseUrl property. Edit the config file of your service or use the Administration-App (there you set the "Web Client Base Url" under Client Services). You set it to `HTTP://<Servername>:<Port>/<Instancename>` (depending on your configuration, but Port should be *8080*).
2. Restart the Service (obviously)
3. **Restart Visual Studio Code**. Yes, that is a not very intuitive, but a really crucial step.

After that, you should be able to publish to the Server without problems.